# Average color of bottom 30% of an image

Tags: android, image, colors, pixel

I am trying to write a method to get the average color of the bottom 30% of an image. I'm trying to do this by going over each pixel individually, getting their colors, summing them op and dividing the result by the amount of pixels I checked. My code is:

```
int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
int pixel;
int pixelSumRed = 0;
int pixelSumBlue = 0;
int pixelSumGreen = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 70; j < 100; j++) {
        pixel = image.getPixel((int) Math.round((i/100)*imageWidth), (int) Math.round((j/100)*imageHeight));
        pixelSumRed += Color.red(pixel);
        pixelSumBlue += Color.blue(pixel);
        pixelSumGreen += Color.green(pixel);
        Log.d("Checks", "Pixel " + i + ", " + j + " red: " + Color.red(pixel) + ", green: " + Color.green(pixel) + ", blue: " + Color.blue(pixel));
        }
    }

averagePixelRed = pixelSumRed / 3000;
averagePixelBlue = pixelSumBlue / 3000;
averagePixelGreen = pixelSumGreen / 3000;
```

Now, I noticed that the same color is printed for each pixel, so for one image I'll get RGB = 210, 44, 70 for each pixel and for another image I'll get RGB = 12, 0, 90 for each pixel. Obviously something is wrong but I can't find what it is. I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wonders of integer division!  When you divide your i or j by 100, it is done as integer division, and it rounds down - you'll get 0 each time.  You can re-order it to do:

```
(i * imageWidth) / 100
```